# Running SQL files on S3 in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to upload SQL files to S3 like:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT ...
UPDATE ...
COMMIT;
```

And have them loaded into S3 directly? We currently have dumps going in through `COPY` but we have large changes that are provided through SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy command executes only CSV files ( any delimiter separated files).
if you have file as you mententkoned. You can use java program / or php to read the file and run query one by one.
another way is use pgsql command line to run sql files. 
You can not run sql files directly from s3 as we do for copy commands